# Will Canonical be dumping a standard file manager for non-root users in coming releases?

Tags: nautilus

Just the title - are they really going to do that?

Comment: Do you mean are they removing Nautilus, as I haven't heard anything to suggest they are.

Comment: srsly? they dumped root login and you want to know if they are dumping file manager for non-root? sorry, it makes my head hurt.  i would like to know how you thought that might be happening

Comment: Well it wasn't a suggestion by any means. I ask because using Unity shows that there is definitely a shift away from a standard file manager. Well "root" login could be an administrator/owner account. For plain user accounts, having another file manager seems superfluous.

Comment: Oh buddy you seriosly don't want to login with the root account... and one thing is a File Manager and another completely different things is the Desktop Interface, that somehow you mixed up.

Comment: @UriHerrera I know I don't want to login with the root account. but it seems as though nautilus is becoming less and less relevent. I really wouldn't be surprised if its not there in 13.04.

Comment: Well you never said where you see that happnening ever, and no a file manager will never get irrelevant in computing, even phones have file managers.

Comment: @UriHerrera, as it goes, I did address this in a response but it was deleted. I'm not even sure why. The file manager as we know it, is pretty superfluous. I don't doubt that people need to view their files but the number of ways to do it needs to be reduced. I think it makes more sense for the individula apps to index the relevant files they open instead of relying on people to organise their files adequately for maximum efficiency.

Comment: @davbren I recommend editing your question to include the explanations from comments for why you thought such a change might be made. Right now, your question makes sense when the comments are taken into consideration, but many people (understandably) may not read through all of them.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure where the question came from, but no. Nautilus remains the file manager for GNOME, and Ubuntu.